# Place <> symbol around factor NAs so it looks like <NA>

Tags: r

Is there a way to put the <> symbol around factor NAs so it looks like 
I believe I've seen this done before.

I have a bunch of state names with 2 letters in caps, so having just NA doesn't really stand out very much.

Comment: Do you mean to change `NA` value to `"<NA>"` string, and leave `"NA"` string as `"NA"`? If so, then try: `myData$myColumn[ is.na(myData$myColumn) ] <- "<NA>"`

Comment: I think that might not work if `myColumn` is a factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert NAs to an explicit factor level using `fct_explicit_na` from `forcats` (part of `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)
c(NA, NA, 'KY', 'LA', 'MD') %>% 
  fct_explicit_na('<NA>')
```

Comment: That did work really well, thanks!

Do you by any chance also know if this is possible with Integer NAs? I have some NAs hiding in 2 digit numbers and it's not impossible to find them, but this trick might prove useful there as well.

Comment: I often convert number/integers to factors for plotting, for example when grouping numbers (>15, <0, etc.) or when I need to plot NAs explicitly. This can be however be treacherous since when you convert the factor back to numeric it's using the numbers underneath the factor levels rather than the actual numbers. - So I'd use that with caution.

Comment: Yeah gotta put it into a character first right?

Ah ok, I'll look into plotting NAs. That's for the tips!

Comment: That's correct. If you feel like this answer solved your problem, you can click the checkbox to accept it (unless of course you'd like to wait for more solutions).

Comment: Done. Didn't even know that was there as this was my first post. Good experience so far :)

Comment: Cool! Thank you!! :)